# Responsive / Relative Positioning Background Image

Tags: css, responsive-design

Issue I'm having is the background image on the anchor as a **before** element needs to move with the text as you resize your screen.

I need the background image to maintain it's position ( e.g left: 20px;) with the text as you resize your screen.

Here is my CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;

}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    color: #717171;
}

ul li a:before {
    background: url(http://graphicclouds.com/wp-content/uploads/img/73-google-style-icons-thumb.jpg) no-repeat -11px -26px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

.link-1:before {
    left: 20px;
}

.link-2:before {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2KHS6/

All suggestions welcome

Comment: The problem comes with `text-align: center;`. You want the text to be aligned on the left with a margin or padding that is the same size as the image.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I need the text centered so that when the user resizes the screen the text is still in the center with the background image positioned correctly to the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New version:

> http://jsfiddle.net/2KHS6/5/

Hope it fills your needs. You might want to set a `min-width` to avoid problems with small screens though. I did this basically:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* So things don't get crazy */
    min-width: 160px;
    /* center the child, the <a> */
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #717171;
    /* Should be the same height as the img so it stays centered */
    line-height: 33px;
}

ul li a:before {
    background: url(http://graphicclouds.com/wp-content/uploads/img/73-google-style-icons-thumb.jpg) no-repeat -11px -26px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    /* position the image at the left of the a. There are many methods to do this actually */
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and very close! 

I need the text centered (hence it's there - sorry forgot to mention!) so that when the user resizes the screen the text is still in the center with the background image positioned correctly to the left

Comment: Do you want to center it respect the 50% of the screen, or respect of the whitespace between icons?

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen when the screen is too small and the text doesn't fit?

Comment: Ideally the whole anchor to be 50% as the parent list item width is set to 50%. The image to be around 20px to the left of the text.

Comment: Edited again, I think I missunderstood you the first time.